# Easy way to detect modifier keys (e.g. Ctrl-P) in GTK / Glade in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gtk, glade

I'm looking for a way to detect key combinations, such as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> sequence (hold down <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd>, hit the <kbd>P</kbd> key), from within `key_press_event` handlers for a widget. There doesn't seem to be any easy clean way to tell whether a modifier key is held down.

The clunky way is:

1. Write and bind both `keypress` and `key-release` handlers
2. Store press and release of the modifier keys I care about, to know when they're held down (<kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd>, etc., keys are different)
3. Detect press of letter-keys I care about, and treat them differently depending on which modifier keys are held down.

AccelGroup (see answer below) seems to work for most purposes, but they're per-window, not per-widget.

Comment: Take a look at [accelerator groups](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the key press event the event structure (GdkEventKey) has a member called `state` that tells you which modifiers (including mouse buttons) are currently pressed. You will need to mask the state with the ruby version of `gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask` to mask out caps-lock and num-lock etc.

Comment: You are right. In Ruby/Glade there's also event_key.state.control_mask? which is true iff a control key is hit. (I can't find it documented anywhere.) The key handler gets key-press events for the Control key, just like it was an ordinary key, but the keycode is 0xffe3 (for left ctrl) or 0xffe4 (for right ctrl) (on my keyboard) so they're easy to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Accelerator groups appear to do most of what I was looking for. Ruby documentation is in http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/ja/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3AAccelGroup.

It appears that an AccelGroup can bind key-combinations to a block or closure, and the AccelGroup is then added to a window.

Hat tip and +1 to "another.anon.coward."

(However, they are per-window, not per-widget.)